# Designing a self-power current range detector

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, current-measurement, low-power, current-transformer

I need to design a current range detector i.e. a module with an AC current as input and a digital output. When the current is within range (i.e. between 0.1A AC to 2.5A AC), the output should be a digital high, else low (The digital output can be a simple Potential Free Contact in the form of an optocoupler that is turned on when the current is within range).

This is pretty simple to design using an external power supply. Using a 1000:1 CT along with a shunt on the secondary side to step down the primary current into acceptable voltage, we can then sense the voltage across the shunt via a micro-controller which does RMS calculation and driving the optocoupler via microcontroller if the RMS is within the range.

**The challenge here is that I don't have access to an external power source** & I don't want to rely on batteries. So the circuit has to be self-powered, i.e. drawing power from the input current itself.

This is not that difficult. One can charge a capacitor via the input current (using an h-bridge) and then use voltage across this capacitor for power supply to drive the microcontroller & the optocoupler.

I am wondering if something even simpler can be constructed using just passive components & an optocoupler (i.e. avoiding a microcontroller). Something like 2 CTs each with different shunts with one CT to detect the upper limit and the other to detect the lower limit and then to take an analog AND of these two somehow to drive the optocoupler. One can easily convert RMS to DC voltage using a circuit as below (Source: https://patents.google.com/patent/US6856185B2/en) where input is an AC voltage and output is converted DC voltage proportional to the AC voltage's RMS.

[image]

Can anyone help me out here with some design ideas?

FYI, timing and accuracy are not at all important here. The module is not time-sensitive. It is acceptable if the digital output changes after 2-3 seconds from the time there is a change in the input current. What's important is to keep the module as simple as possible (and as cheap as possible) while being reliable. Up to 5% inaccuracy is acceptable.

Comment: Have you looked at the RIBXGA-SCAL at all?

Answer (score 2):

> This is pretty simple to design using an external power supply. Using a 1000:1 CT along with a shunt on the secondary side to step down the primary current into acceptable voltage, we can then sense the voltage across the shunt via a micro-controller which does RMS calculation and driving the optocoupler via microcontroller if the RMS is within the range.

This is your solution. Remove microcontroller. Add a window comparator.

Key insight: *into acceptable voltage* - exactly, you want a voltage range that at the minimum lets you light a LED in an optocoupler.

The circuit would have several operating ranges:

1. Input voltage below V2 - output OFF.
2. Input voltage crosses V2 - output turns ON, LED load causes the input voltage to drop to V1. Low-end comparator's hysteresis accommodates that.
3. Input voltage crosses V3 - output turns OFF, load drop causes the voltage to increase to V4. High-end comparator's hysteresis accommodates that.

To get a DC voltage, rectify the input and use it to power a dual low-power comparator with a reference voltage source built in. Four diodes, a bunch of resistors, a capacitor, optocoupler, a dual comparator with reference, a transistor or two - that's it.

The comparator's quiescent current is negligible compared to the LED current, so some large load resistor on the transformer output would provide the current-to-voltage scale factor when the LED is OFF. When the LED is ON, it can be driven by a constant-current source made out of two transistors for example.

The comparators' outputs can be logically combined using e.g. the very transistors that drive the LED: one transistor for high side drive, one for low side drive.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Figures 1: [NK Technologies](https://www.nktechnologies.com/current-indicators/aci-amp-flasher/). Figure 2: [CR Magnetics](https://www.crmagnetics.com/remote/cr2550).*

Some of these remote current sensing indicator units might do the job for you. The blue ones seem to have a flasher so probably not what you want. The CR Magnetics one may have a unipolar LED so you might want one that turns on in both directions. You would cut off the LED and feed the opto-LED instead. Ideally you'd get one with a sensitivity of 2.5 A or so and wind five turns on the primary to get sensitivity to 0.5 A.

Your driven circuit would have to do the related logic and timing though.